# Convert ActionResult to pdf in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, actionresult

My tool is trying to call an API query from the server as:

```
public class WKPDFConvertionResult : ActionResult {...}


public  PDFController ： Controller
{
    private WKPDFConvertionResult getPdf(int Id)
    {
        return new WKPDFConvertionResult()
        {
            Filename = filename,
            Footer = true,
            Html = htmlWriter.ToString()
        };
    }

    public ActionResult PDF (int id)
    {
        return getPDF(id);
    }
}
```

If I use firefox to open the query:

```
http://localhost:60653/pdf/1
```

the browser will automatically pop up a file download dialog;

If I use the same query by

```
API.Query(http://local host:60653/pdf/1)
```

I think it returns a binary for the same pdf. However when I tried:

```
Byte[] btText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(API.Query(http://local host:60653/pdf/1) )));
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(btText))
using (FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_outputPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    memStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

The pdf that it generates at _outputPath shows blank in pdf viewer, although its file size is reasonable (more than 80kb).

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, I don't know why the pdf viewer doesn't show the contents, although it contains

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (�� C o m m i t t e e)
```

and other stuff that makes it seems to be a reasonable pdf file.

EDIT:

To compare, if I open both files in notepad, I will see the original file as:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ C o m m i t t e e)
```

so maybe the encoding and decoding do not use the same thing, but I have no idea what is the original encoding though...

Any helps will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure you save the file content only? Or you store the rest of web response also?

Comment: What's the diff of the two results get you?

Comment: @lavrik The end of the file contains trailer
<<
/Size 50
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 25 0 R
>>
startxref
41574
%%EOF
 so I think it is the file content only?

Comment: @lc. hmm its pretty hard to tell. If I compare bothe files on notepad, it seems the encoding is different? for example, the original file contains: þÿ while the other is : �� but I don't know what is the original coding though..

Comment: Hmm, have you tried just saving the binary data without going through a text encoding?

Comment: @lc. I have to convert it to a stream in order to save it as a file isn't it?

Comment: Streams are not required to be character streams, are they? Byte streams should do.